# Firebase Firestore - View Realtime Listeners & Unsubscribe Listeners on JavaScript Client SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do you view active realtime listeners on a browser/client? [Handle listen errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#handle_listen_errors) documentation indicates

> After an error, the listener will not receive any more events

but I just wanted to validate / verify that my listener is unsubscribed after certain events.

Here's my code snippet. There is a `cart` field in my user document that stores an `orderId` pointing to a document in a separate `orders` collection. On signin, I want to listen to the returned `user.uid` document in my `users` collection. If there is an order in their cart (e.g. `cart: h4the-cart-uid-7rhksjn`), I want to listen to that specific order - if not (e.g. `null` or `""`, detach any listeners on that order (the crux of my problem, old orderId is gone). My issue is unsubscribing the listeners so that I'm not throwing `insufficient privilege` / `not authorized` errors bcs the listener is still active after user empties their cart, or user signed out.

It would be nice if I could just say `unsubscribe` to the parent collection...

```
var userDocListener;
var orderDocListener;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    userDocListener = function(){
      return firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(function (userDoc) {
        if(userDoc.exists){
          if(userDoc.data().cart == null || !userDoc.data().cart){
            //user cart empty HOW TO UNSUBSCRIBE W/O THE ORDER ID?
            cartBadgeDisplayHandler();
            if(window.location.pathname === "/account" || window.location.pathname === "account"){
              accountPageCartTabOrderNoOrderView();
            }
            orderDocListener();
          } else {
            orderDocListener = function () {
              return firebase.firestore().collection("orders").doc(userDoc.data().cart).onSnapshot(function (orderDoc) {
                cartBadgeDisplayHandler(orderDoc);
              });
            }
            orderDocListener();
          }
        }
      });
    }
    userDocListener();
  } else {
    // no user HOW TO UNSUBSCRIBE W/O THE USER UID?
    userDocListener();
  }
});
```

Comment: Answer below, but this sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). We might be able to help better if you explain more precisely you're trying to accomplish/solve.

Answer (score -1):

There is no API that lists active listeners. If you need such a list, you will need track it yourself.

Comment: My issue boils down to passing a variable to an `.onSnapshot` listener. The documentation indicates you basically use a function expression, e.g. `var myDocListener = fireb..doc(myVar).onSnapshot`. You call that function once to enable it, call it again to disable it. So, I'm troubleshooting how to do this ...

Comment: If you're having problems with a specific piece of code, edit your question to include that specific code in your question please. That will make it much easier for anyone to see what you're doing, and where you might be going wrong (or might need to go next).